# OpenFeint-Style Framework for Webapps

Tags: html, web-applications, game-center

I am developing a game webapp. However, I would like it to have a leaderboard, achievements, etc. Is there a framework like OpenFeint that can be used with webapps? I have been searching for a while, and haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with their new REST api:
http://support.openfeint.com/dev/openfeint-restful-api-settings/

Comment: I noticed this. However, as far as I can see, it's read-only. Correct me if I'm wrong, though!